# Repeated value in useDelimiter()

Tags: java

I have this string for example

```
 String input = "1 2 fish1 3 4 fish2 5 6 fish3 7 8 fish1 9 10 fish2 11 12..."; 

 pairs1 = new Scanner(file.txt).useDelimiter("fish1");
 String inputPairs1=pairs1.next().trim();
 System.out.println(inputPairs1);

 pairs2 = new Scanner(pairs1.next()).useDelimiter("fish2");
 String inputPairs2=pairs2.next().trim(); 
 System.out.println(inputPairs2);

 pairs3 = new Scanner(pairs2.next()).useDelimiter("fish3");
 String inputPairs3=pairs2.next().trim();
 System.out.println(inputPairs3);

 pairs4 = new Scanner(pairs3.next()).useDelimiter("fish1");
 String inputPairs4=pairs4.next().trim();
 System.out.println(inputPairs4);

 pairs5 = new Scanner(pairs4.next()).useDelimiter("fish2");
 String inputPairs5=pairs5.next().trim();
 System.out.println(inputPairs5);
```

Output:

```
1 2

3 4

5 6
```

The data reading breaks after second fish1

Expected output:

```
1 2

3 4

5 6

7 8

9 10
```

I want to read the data if the value in the delimiter is repeated. Is regex a good option?

Comment: Could you please explain the logic behind the output? Do you just want to remove the first instance of the delimiter and then print out each token?

Comment: @GBlodgett  I want to store the data between all the fish string for example I want to store 1 2 as a string between fish1 and fish2. I could achieve this using useDelimiter(). when I try to use usedelimiter for fish1 for the second time the data is not read. I need the values between all the fish to display later

Comment: How are you reading from the `Scanner`? Please provide a [MCVE]

Comment: yes I am using scanner to save the values in between to a string and then to a map. I want to read the values further but the scanner object is empty in the above case

Comment: Yes but *how* are you reading from the `Scanner`? Please provide your code

Comment: You need to show all the code. We can't invent the code that `...` represents. --- Also, the code doesn't compile. Fix it. --- And since you never use space as delimiter, how come `1` and `2` are shown on separate lines? How is the output even generated, given that you have no `print` statements in the code? --- Let me second [comment by GBlodgett](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53013835/repeated-value-in-usedelimiter#comment92931550_53013835): Please provide a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Andreas please check the updated code

Comment: @c.r Code still doesn't compile. Please test your code before posting it, so we don't have to waste our time to even reproduce your problem.

Comment: @Andreas I just want to know if there is an alternative to useDelimiter(value) where the value is not omitted and and can be used to scan further

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You (presumably) create a `Scanner` called `pairs1` on the given text, and call its `next()` method twice.

First call returns `"1 2 "` *(value is printed)*
Second call returns `" 3 4 fish2 5 6 fish3 7 8 "`
Third call would return `" 9 10 fish2 11 12..."` is you ever called it, but you don't.

Scanner `pairs2` is created with text `" 3 4 fish2 5 6 fish3 7 8 "`
First call returns `" 3 4 "` *(value is printed)*
Second call returns `" 5 6 fish3 7 8 "`
Third call throws `NoSuchElementException`

Why are you surprised by this?
Or is it that you intended `String inputPairs3 = pairs2.next().trim();` to call `pairs3`, not `pairs2`?

Ok, let's assume you did and fix that, so there is no third call to `pairs2`.

Scanner `pairs3` is created with text `" 5 6 fish3 7 8 "`
First call returns `" 5 6 "` *(value is printed)*
Second call returns `" 7 8 "`

Scanner `pairs4` is created with text `" 7 8 "`
First call returns `" 7 8 "` *(value is printed)*
Second call throws `NoSuchElementException`

---

If you simply want value pairs, and don't care whether separator is `fish1`, `fish2`, or `fish3`, simply split on either, i.e. set delimiter to all of them (delimiter *is* a regex):

```
String input = "1 2 fish1 3 4 fish2 5 6 fish3 7 8 fish1 9 10 fish2 11 12...";

try (@SuppressWarnings("resource") Scanner sc = new Scanner(input).useDelimiter("fish[123]")) {
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        String inputPairs = sc.next().trim();
        System.out.println(inputPairs);
    }
}
```

*Output*

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10
11 12...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `java.util.regex.Pattern` and the replaceFirst method:

```
String input = "1 2 fish1 1 2 fish2 1 2 fish3 1 2 fish1 1 2 fish2 1 2...";

String s = input.replaceFirst(Pattern.quote("fish1"), "");
```